# Do the User defined runtime Attributes works only on custom classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using `storyboard` and there are 5 view controllers in it. Each `ViewController` has only 1 UIButton. I want to set button's background color using User Defined Runtime Attributes. So I defined a keyPath "bgColor" and set corresponding hex color code "#ffaa11".  But application crashes before loading the view. It gives exception:

```
[<UIRoundedRectButton 0x713fdb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bgColor.
```

I dont want to create custom class. Please suggest how can I paas value through IB. Please check the snapshot.

NOTE: In real my requirement is to get a string value which has been entered in Interface Builder. Very similar to User Defined Runtime attributes. I have taken example of bg color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using User Defined Runtime Attributes anyway? Switch to the Attributes Inspector and choose button's background from there.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No actually my requirement is something else. In real I need to retrieve a string value dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first.

**Obviously it crashes. Because there is no `bgColor` property on the button. Hence when you are trying to set it as `button.bgColor = #yourValue`. It is crashing.**

If you are using ios7 try setting the button's tintColor property. and for styles go through `tintAdjustmentMode` values.

And after these . If it still doesn't solve your issue. We will discuss something else :) :)

cheers. Have fun.